# MacBook Pro will not boot

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup

When I turned on the Mac I get three tones, a circle image with diagonal line and wont boot.

I restarted it in safe mode and got a text msg. For a couple of seconda, then disappeared, saying

> Panic 0 msg
>
> Your pc restarted due to a problem

I restarted it once again with recovery keys. I think Cmd+R or Alt+R

And got the Get os x utilities menu:

- Restore time machine
- Reinstall os x
- Disk utility

I tried restorin os and told me I had no Internet connection.

I selected disk utility option and when I clicked on disk 1 this information came up:

```
Select dsk:disk1 - os x base sys 1.26 gb
Appe partitipn map
Repair disk unavailable.
Verify disk unavailable
```

When I clicked on the ST disk this information came up:

```
500.11 gb GB ST9500325A...
Veryfying....
Volume recovery HD seems to be ok
Partition map appers ok
```

I don't know why it wont boot.

How can I proceed from here to get my system back?

Comment: Hello benwiggy, I finally found the model: A1286.         MBP 15" Core 17 2.2 Ghz/4GB/500 GB

Comment: Updated answer with new info.

Answer (score 2):

Here's Apple's Support document about error beeps at startup.
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202768

That's a 2011 MBP. Realistically, you need to have this physically inspected by someone. Given its age, I'd suggest looking for a local repair shop who works with Apple kit. (An Apple Store will say it's too old.)

If this is the original hard drive, then I would expect it to fail at any time, if it hasn't already. Replacing it with an SSD would be a cost-effective way to increase the life-span of this Mac. Maxing the RAM to 16 Gb would also help; though this is assuming that there aren't any other hardware problems.

Comment: No I have not. Thanks for your help. Will read  document now